# how to check cursor if value null?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i use Sqlite and run in android application.

i have code like this :

```
//get ALL Data
public Cursor getAll() throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    else if(mCursor.isNull(0))
    {
        Log.d("data", "null");
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

my trouble if value null the application force close such >_<. I want if value null then print log ??

please any body solve my trouble??

Comment: you can check like this `mcursor.getCount() > 0`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to nest those `if` blocks:

```
...
if (mCursor != null)
{
     mCursor.moveToFirst();

     if (mCursor.isNull(0))
     {
         Log.d("data", "null");
     }
}
return mCursor;
```

The `else if` block in your code was only running if `mCursor` was null, in which case `mCursor.isNull(0)` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call isNull on a null pointer. the if statement means it work call isNull unless the mCursor object is null, which will throw a NullPointerException - which causes a crash. try removing the if after the else. that will log "null" if the mCursor is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that cursor Move or not

```
if (cursorinfo.moveToFirst())
{
if value then show data here.
}
else
{
Log here
}
```